# How to compile NPAPI plugin sourcecode using Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, google-chrome, dll, npapi, gecko

(First, sorry for bad English ! )

I downloaded the source code here : http://minimizetotray.googlecode.com/files/SourceCode.zip - which is a NPAPI plugin that has the ability to  minimize Chrome windows to system tray.

Using Visual Studio 9.0, I opened the file chromeTray.vcproj (located in DLL dir of SourceCode.zip ), tried compiling the project to get a dll but I got alot of [error messages](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26772029/Images/Errors%20when%20compiling%20ChromeTray.JPG) !

Opening chromeTray.vcproj using Notepad, I found that it has some references to [XULRunner SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_SDK) but i dont know how to use that SDK with Visual Studio and I not sure if I need anything else to get it work.

Anyone can take a look and tell me what I need to get this sourceCode work ( creating the dll )? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that project, but from the list of your errors, it looks like you're missing an inclusion of `atlbase.h`. Given `atlbase.h` is indeed included in the project's `stdafx.h`, there seems to be some compilation unit that doesn't include `stdafx.h` first.

Try having the compiler show the list of includes during compilation (Project settings -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Show Includes in my VC8), and see who's including ATL headers before `atlbase.h`.

Comment: What was the order of includes during compilation? I'd expect to see some inclusions before stdafx.h is included. If for some reason you couldn't get it to work, you can try monitoring file activity using ProcMon (filter on cpp and h files during compilation).

Comment: Is this what you want? http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26772029/output.txt ( altbase.h was included in project's stdafx.h )